# NodeJS mysql query returns empty result

Tags: mysql, node.js, http-request-parameters

i'm new to NodeJS (duh!).
I know it executes functions asynchronous but I still cannot see what causes this phenomenon:

I am using the express and mysql modules and trying to execute an SQL query based on request parameters. It is supposed to be a simple validation API feature where the server is going to lookup a user in a database by listening on a specific URL for two request parameters (user and passwd).

The problem is that **the SQL query always returns an empty object as result when I do this using the request parameters in the query.**

However, **if i hard code the query and run it outside the app.get(...) I get the desired result!** But I need this to work on demand by request...

(I'm not intending to use GET-request later on, this example is for debugging purposes :))

What am i doing wrong here?

Here's my code:

```
// Server and Mysql setup here 
var app = require('express').createServer(),
    SERVER_PORT = 8080;
var Client = require('mysql').Client,
    client = new Client(),
    ...
// User, password and database setup here, cropped out from this example //
// ...

function validateUser(user, passwd, callback) {
client.query('SELECT date FROM '+CUSTOMERS_TABLE+' WHERE email="'+user+'" AND passwd="'+passwd+'";',
    function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(fields);
        callback(results);
    });
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
if((typeof query[REQ_PARAM_USER] != 'undefined' && typeof query[REQ_PARAM_PASSWD] != 'undefined')
        && (query[REQ_PARAM_USER] != '' && query[REQ_PARAM_PASSWD] != '')) {
        validateUser(REQ_PARAM_USER, REQ_PARAM_PASSWD, function(results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
    }
    res.end("End")
});
app.listen(SERVER_PORT);

console.log('Server running at port '+SERVER_PORT);
```

Oh, and by the way, console.log(fields) outputs the correct fields! But why not the results?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the wrong parameters to `validateUser`:

```
validateUser(REQ_PARAM_USER, REQ_PARAM_PASSWD, // ...
```

What you really want:

```
validateUser(query[REQ_PARAM_USER], query[REQ_PARAM_PASSWD], // ...
```

**Edit:** A few other issues with your code:

- You don't have to parse the url. Express does this for you, and the query is available as `req.query`.
- You shouldn't `throw` in asynchronous code. It will give unexpected results. Instead, stick to the nodejs paradigm of passing `(err, results)` to all callbacks, and do proper error checking where you can -- i.e., in your `verifyUser`, pass along the error with the `callback` and check for errors in your `get` handler. Either `res.send(500)` (or something) when you get an error, or pass it along to the express error handler by calling `next(err)`.

  ```
  validateUser(query[REQ_PARAM_USER], query[REQ_PARAM_PASSWD], function(err, results) {
      if(err) {
          console.error(err);
          res.send(500);
      } else {
          console.log(results);
          res.send(results);
      }
  });
  ```
- Never pass query parameters directly to something like an SQL query. Instead, use parameters for your SQL query:

  ```
  client.query('SELECT date FROM '+CUSTOMERS_TABLE+' WHERE email=? AND passwd=?', [user, passwd], // ...
  ```